# SQL Oracle - CASE WHEN for separately ID's

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have some (thousands ;)) ID's and I'm trying check their relationship separately. But I have problem with checking relationship for each ID independently. Actualy my code check this for all ID`s beetwen them..

Table for example

```
ID  Service 
1   A
1   A1
2   A
2   B
3   A
3   A1
```

SQL code

```
SELECT a.ID, a.service,
CASE 
    WHEN a.service IN ('A','A1') THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
END      
FROM t1 a
```

Output

```
ID  Service  RELATION
1   A        YES
1   A1       YES
2   A        NO
2   B        NO
3   A        YES
3   A1       YES
```

Comment: And what do you want to do, what is you desired output?

Comment: I Added to post desired output. Now my code related all ID's betwen them, but I want to check related only within given ID.

Comment: @user10066915 Could you explain the problem elaborately? It is not clear what exactly the issue you are having!

Comment: First create a table of all such  relationships and then it becomes easier to join and filter the rows from this table.

Comment: And when would you say that services are related? When name of one service is a substring of name or another service with the same ID? And are there some additional possibilities?

Comment: Any ID shoud have two services "A" and "A1" I want to check all servces to have it.

Comment: Based on your desired output it appears that you want all records with the same ID that have the same first letter for SERVICE labelled with 'YES'. Are there any other rules ?

Comment: Pair of services are different. I have about 15 pairs A-A1, CE-FR, PQ-LR, etc. They have no any rules, Someone just invented these alfanumeric codes.

Comment: @user10066915  I can see that row with ID 2 and Service 'A' is not set to 'YES' in your desired output. Is that because there is no 'A1' service also, for that ID 2?

Comment: Yes, 'A' and 'A1' must be in this id for set 'YES'.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should sort your table according to service alphabetically.
Then create an array and populate it with all the services:

```
DECLARE 
   CURSOR c_t1 is 
   SELECT  service FROM t1; 
   type c_list is varray (6) of t1.service%type; 
   service_list c_list := c_list(); 
   counter integer :=0; 
BEGIN 
   FOR n IN c_t1 LOOP 
      counter := counter + 1; 
      service_list.extend; 
      service_list(counter)  := n.service; 
      dbms_output.put_line('Service('||counter ||'):'||service_list(counter)); 
   END LOOP; 
END; 
/
```

Then iterate through your table values:

```
DECLARE
        v_count number DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT t1.ID, t1.service FROM t1)
    LOOP
        FOR j IN (service_list.COUNT)
        LOOP
            CASE 
                WHEN t1.service IN (service_list[i], service_list[i+1]) THEN 'Yes'
                ELSE 'No'
            END      
            v_COUNT := v_COUNT + 1;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_COUNT);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query works though I'm not sure how it would perform.

```
WITH a1
     AS (SELECT id, 1 AS here
         FROM   services
         WHERE  service = 'A1')
   , a
     AS (SELECT id, 1 AS here
         FROM   services
         WHERE  service = 'A')
SELECT driver.id
     , driver.service
     , CASE
          WHEN NVL(a1.here, 0) + NVL(a.here, 0) > 1 THEN 'YES'
          ELSE 'NO'
       END
FROM   services driver
       LEFT OUTER JOIN a1 ON a1.id = driver.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON a.id = driver.id
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I have problem with checking relationship for each ID
>   independently

That is why it is suggested to you to create a new table storing all the unique relationships between the services. This gives you a better handle to compare the relations and give you the desired output.

You should start by creating the relationship table which stores values like this.

```
|rid| S1 | S2 |
--- |----|----|
|1  |  A | A1 |
```

Now, to generate your desired output, you should first use a self join to get the pairs of relations with common `ID`s .

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.service,
       b.service
FROM   t1 a 
       join t1 b 
         ON ( a.service != b.service 
              AND a.id = b.id ) ;
```

Once you have got such combinations, all you would need is to check if that combination of relation exists using an `OUTER JOIN` with relationship table, which will help you to get the output as "YES" or "NO" based on the existence.

```
SELECT a.id, 
       b.service, 
       CASE 
         WHEN r.id IS NULL THEN 'NO' 
         ELSE 'YES' 
       END AS relation 
FROM   t1 a 
       join t1 b 
         ON ( a.service != b.service 
              AND a.id = b.id ) 
       left join rel r 
              ON ( ( r.s1 = a.service 
                     AND r.s2 = b.service ) 
                    OR ( r.s2 = a.service 
                         AND r.s1 = b.service ) );
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c22c6a/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would use *window* function :

```
select t1.*, (case when sum(case when service not in ('A', 'A1') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) = 0
                   then 'yes' else 'no'
              end) as Relation
from t1;
```

Comment: On the face of it this works so why the downvote ?

Answer (score 0):

this will work and you have to use decode function for it:

```
create table ex2(
no1 number,
no2 varchar(20));
insert into ex2 values(1,    'A');
insert into ex2 values(1   , 'A1');
insert into ex2 values(2   , 'A');
insert into ex2 values(2   , 'B');
insert into ex2 values(3   , 'A');
insert into ex2 values(3   , 'A1');
select * from ex2;

SELECT no1, no2 ,
decode(no2,'A','yes','A1','yes','no')      
FROM ex2;
```

output:

```
1   A   yes
2   A   yes
2   B   no
3   A   yes
3   A1  yes
1   A1  yes
```

for your table query is :

```
SELECT ID, service ,
decode(service,'A','yes','A1','yes','no')
FROM ex2;
```

Comment: @user10066915  is it working???

Comment: This doesn't work as both the rows with ID 2 should show a value of NO.

Comment: @britesponge my inputs set is different